# switch VS if which is faster when not comparing =?

Tags: c

I know that usually switch case is faster than if else if when whe are talking about something like this

```
if (a==0) statement1;
else if (a==1) statement2;
else if (a==2) statement3;
else statement4;
```

In this case it should be easier for the compiler to perform efficiently

```
switch (a){
case 0:
statement1;
break;
case 1:
statement2;
break;
case 2:
statement3;
break;
default:
statement4;
}
```

But I do not know what hapens with the next code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int value;
    puts("introduce a value (0-1000)");
    scanf("%i" , &value);
    if(value > 400) printf("%i is greater than 400", value);
    else if (value >300) printf("%i is smaller than 401 and greater than 300", value);
    else if (value >200) printf("%i is smaller than 301 and greater than 200", value);
    else if (value > 100) printf("%i is smaller than 201 and greater than 100", value);
    else printf("%i is smaller than 101", value);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it faster than this one?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(){
    int value;
    puts("introduce a value (0-1000)");
    scanf("%i" , &value);
    switch(value){
        case 401 ... INT_MAX:
        printf("%i is greater than 400", value);
        break;
        case 301 ... 400:
        printf("%i is samller than 401 and greater than 300", value);
        break;
        case 201 ... 300:
        printf("%i is samller than 301 and greater than 200", value);
        break;
        case 100 ... 200:
        printf("%i is samller than 201 and greater than 100", value);
        break;
        default:
        printf("%i is samller than 101", value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Every branch has a printf(), so why worry?

Comment: `switch` is generally a good choice for limited contiguous values. But then don't believe me and always collect the performance data for both cases and compare yourself. This data may surprise you from time to time.

Comment: This was just an example, I am using it in an embedded system where it has no printf() at all...

Comment: `case 401 ... INT_MAX:` is GNU extension, it's not standard C.

Comment: So it doesn´t make any change to use greater than statements and not equals. Am I right?